# Why var x display incorrectly?

Tags: c++, variables, syntax, codeblocks

```
    #include <iostream> // подключаем библиотеку ввода-вывода
    #include <cmath> // подключаем библиотеку математических функций

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    float a, x, y = 0; // объявление переменных
    cout << "Enter a variable: ";
    cin >> a; // запрос на ввод a
    cout << "Enter x variable: ";
    cin >> x; // запрос на ввод x
    cout << "a = " << a << ", x = " << x; // вывод a и x
    y = (pow(x, 3) + sqrt(1 + pow(x, 3))) / (a + exp(x)); // формула расчета
    cout << y;
    }

Enter a variable: 6
Enter x variable: 7
a = 6, x = 70.327894
```

I can't understand why x == 70, when it must be 7. Also I don't know why `cout << y;` doesn't work. If I delete `y = ...` and `cout << y`, x display correctly.
I think, that it's my fault, because I'm new in C++ and don't know syntax well.

Comment: Do you know what the value of `y` should be? (My money is on `0.327894`.)

Comment: So your question is "Why does an extra print statement print extra stuff?"

Comment: molbdnilo, I got the same as you in Python, but in C++ not.

Comment: Because you didn't print a newline after it! `<< endl;` Thus, x is 7 and y is 0.327894

Comment: enhzflep, thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're simply printing everything on the same line, you can either:

Print it after your two first result:

```
cout << "a = " << a << ", x = " << x; // вывод a и x
y = (pow(x, 3) + sqrt(1 + pow(x, 3))) / (a + exp(x)); // формула расчета
cout << ", y = " << y;
```

Output:

```
Enter a variable: 6
Enter x variable: 7
a = 6, x = 7, y = 0.327894
```

Or print `y` on another line

```
cout << "a = " << a << ", x = " << x << "\n"; // returns to another line
y = (pow(x, 3) + sqrt(1 + pow(x, 3))) / (a + exp(x)); // формула расчета
cout << "y = " << y;
```

Output:

```
Enter a variable: 6
Enter x variable: 7
a = 6, x = 7
y = 0.327894
```

Answer (score 0):

**a = 6, x = 70.327894**

this doesn't mean **x =70.327894**.

**x is 7** and the result **y is 0.327894**

you need to carefully print to the terminal, use `<< endl;` and add some more labels so you can easily recognize the output of the math calculation...

bottomline: your rocket formula is working fine and you need to take another coffee... :)